# firebase security rules check 2 fields in data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) functions cannot create variables but I need to check two fields for write permissions on my `companies` collection. I have the documentId stored on my `user` document as `company_slug`

So rule #1 for `match /companies/{company} { allow write: ... }` is

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company_slug == company
```

That is fine for read access but I need to check the `user.level` (1 for admin, 2-n for other levels) whether or not a write is OK.

so rule #2 would be

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.level == 1
```

So the complete rule would be:

```
match /companies/{company} {
          allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company_slug == company;
          allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.company_slug == company && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.level == 1;
}
```

Which seems very unwieldy and would also "cost" me 2 reads and 1 write for every write request I send, wouldn't it?

Is there any way to optimize this as this seems very hard to maintain as the application grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to implement you security needs.

You would assign two different Claims to each user :

```
companyId
```

and

`userLevel` (1, 2, 3, etc)

and your rules would look like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userIsLevel1() {
        return (request.auth.uid != null) && (request.auth.token.userLevel == 1);
    }

    function isCorrectCompany(company) {
        return request.auth.token.companyId == company;
    }

    match /companies/{company} {
          allow read: if isCorrectCompany(company);
          allow write: if isCorrectCompany(company) && userIsLevel1();
    }

}
```

One key advantage of using Custom Claims is that you don't need to read one or more Firestore document(s) for each Security Rules verification.

You may watch this official Firebase video, starting at 17:49: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw

Comment: thanks just a quick clarification question before I accept&upvote the answer. The admin SDK is only available server side and so going serverless I would have to set up a google cloud function to call when a user is created to set these claims then & there, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have to set these Claims from a managed environment, i.e. a Cloud Function or another server you manage/control (e.g. node.js). The easiest being probably using a Cloud Function if you go serverless. The doc shows the code to be written in detail.

Comment: What I use to do is the following: I have a `userCreationRequests` collection in which I create a document for each user that needs to be declared/created. Then upon doc creation in this collection, a Cloud Function is triggered which creates the user (through `admin.auth`), assigns the correct claims, and creates a user document in an `appUsers` collection with extra info. You probably don't need the third step in your case. The advantage of doing like that is that you can delegate the user creation to non-admin users to which you assign a specific role.

Comment: perfect. Thanks!